# What is the best way to add _.throttle on a react element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I am struggling to figure out the optimal way to use _.throttle on an onChange element such as input. Apparently it does not work the same as _.debounce.

```
// This works as expected! Replacing 'debounce' with 'throttle' does not work though.
<Input onChange={_.debounce(onInputChange, 1000)} />
```

```
// This does not work. It work as if the wait-time is set to 0
const page = () => {
    const [input, setInput] = React.useState('')

    const onInputChange = () => {
        console.log('Hi!')
    }

return(
    <Input onChange={_.throttle(onInputChange, 1000}/>
)}
```

.

The documentation states that the way to use _.throttle is to make sure you call the function only once

```
// WRONG
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
   _.debounce(doSomething, 300); 
});

// RIGHT
$(window).on('scroll', _.debounce(doSomething, 200));
```

Thank you! Anything helps

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to define a function once for functional components and make sure it's not re-declared/reset every render is to use `useCallback` with no dependencies. Your debounce one may *seem* like it works, but technically the debounce function executes every render, so it's not exactly functioning how you think. So for throttle, debounce and any other similar functions, you can do something like:

```
function App() {
    const [val, setVal] = useState('');
    const onChangeDebounced = useCallback(_.debounce(setVal, 250), []);
    const onChange = e => onChangeDebounced(e.target.value);

    return (
        <input type='text' value={val} onChange={onChange} />
    );
}
```